# Named pipe wait for client in background until client connects

Tags: c++, multithreading, named-pipes

I'm trying to make my named pipe server skip the block-wait of the ConnectNamedPipe function until my client tries to connect. So I want is for my code to continue past the ConnetNamedPipe line until the end but keep the connection for my pipe open in the backgroun. If I use the PIPE_NOWAIT mode when creating the pipe it just returns imediatelly and the pipe closes before my client can connect.

I know that I tried doing this using a thread but even when I create a thread and execute the ConnectNamedPipe part of the code within the thread it still waits on this line instead of continuing with my code. Once it reaches the end of my server cpp file code I want to connect to the pipe with my client.

My Pipe:

```
hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
    lpszPipename,             
    PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,       // one way access, only send data
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe
    PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode
    PIPE_WAIT,                
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, 
    512,
    512,                  
    0,                        
    NULL);                    

if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    Out->msg(ERR,"Creating the pipe failed.");
}

 // Create a thread for this client.
hThread = CreateThread(
    NULL,              // no security attribute
    0,                 // default stack size
    InstanceThread,    // thread proc
    (LPVOID) hPipe,    // thread parameter
    0,                 // not suspended
    &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID

if (hThread == NULL)
{
    Out->msg(ERR,"Creating the thread failed.");
}
else CloseHandle(hThread);

// Close the pipe.
 CloseHandle(hPipe);
```

My Thread:

```
DWORD WINAPI InstanceThread(LPVOID lpvParam)
{
    Out->msg(output::SEV_INFO,"Waiting for client to connect.");
    fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ? //This is where the execution hangs
    TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

    HANDLE hHeap      = GetProcessHeap();
    TCHAR* pchReply   = (TCHAR*)HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));

    DWORD cbBytesRead = 0, cbReplyBytes = 0, cbWritten = 0;
    BOOL fSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hPipe  = NULL;

// The thread's parameter is a handle to a pipe object instance.

    hPipe = (HANDLE) lpvParam;
    uint32_t startTime = time(NULL);
    uint32_t elapsedTime;
// Loop until done reading
    while ((elapsedTime < 60))
    {
        elapsedTime = difftime(time(NULL), startTime);
        // Write to the pipe.
        fSuccess = WriteFile(
            hPipe,        // handle to pipe
            pchReply,     // buffer to write from
            cbReplyBytes, // number of bytes to write
            &cbWritten,   // number of bytes written
            NULL);        // not overlapped I/O

        if (!fSuccess || cbReplyBytes != cbWritten)
        {
            Out->msg(ERR,"InstanceThread WriteFile failed.");
            break;
        }
    }

// Flush the pipe to allow the client to read the pipe's contents
// before disconnecting. Then disconnect the pipe, and close the
// handle to this pipe instance.

    FlushFileBuffers(hPipe);
    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    HeapFree(hHeap, 0, pchReply);

    Out->msg(output::SEV_INFO,"InstanceThread exitting.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named Pipes server, how to interrupt or timeout the wait for client connection and for incoming data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828965/named-pipes-server-how-to-interrupt-or-timeout-the-wait-for-client-connection-a)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to make my named pipe server skip the block-wait of the ConnectNamedPipe function until my client tries to connect.

So you're talking about the server.

> So I want my code to continue past the `ConnectNamedPipe` line while still being able to connect to my server.

So you're talking about the client.

It doesn't make sense. `ConnectNamedPipe()` is a server-side function, and you don't have anything useful to do in a thread dedicated to it except block until a client connects. So do that.

Comment: Whops sorry about that. I've got the ConnectNamedPipe code on my server file. It executes and runs until it hits the thread that contains ConnectNamedPipe. Then it waits for my client to connect. What I want it to do is keep running my code until the end and then when it reaches the end my client will connect to the pipe.

Comment: Keep running till the end of what? How can it do anything with the pipe until the client connects?

Comment: Exactly haha, I've got some other things that I want to do in the code first before the client connects, so I want the code to continue and do these things and then when its done I'll execute the client code and it will connect to this pipe.

Comment: So move the ConnectNamedPipe() call to the point where you're ready to block.

Comment: I would love to do that but I can't since I need the whole server cpp code to finish before I execute the client cpp file. So I just need this thread part of the code to run in the background if that is possible.

Comment: So you want the server to run, execute, and exit, then the client to run, then the server to magically resurrect itself and respond? You're not making much sense. Whatever you may want, ConnectNamedPipe() has to either block or be called in a loop in non-blocking mode, with latency-adding sleeps in between, until the client connects. Period.

Comment: Hey sorry I'm not making much sense Named pipes and threads are new to me so I'm just trying to make as much sense of it as I can. I want it to run in a loop in non-blocking mode with latency-adding sleeps in between. So does that mean I just create the pipe with PIPE_NOWAIT option and add it to a loop that will run it over and over until my client connects to it?

Comment: Why? Why not *block* until a client connects? Do you have something else to do in this thread?

Comment: I am trying to do the same (that is somehow interrupting the wait for client connections, see the `ConnectNamedPipe` part in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828965/named-pipes-server-how-to-interrupt-or-timeout-the-wait-for-client-connection-a)). My motivation is that the user should be able to stop the waiting. But I learned that the use of `PIPE_NOWAIT` in new code is discouraged. Is the only alternative to use blocking mode and either create separate threads or use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` when calling `CreateNamedPipe` ?