# Named Pipes server, how to interrupt or timeout the wait for client connection and for incoming data

Tags: windows, winapi, timeout, named-pipes

I am writing a simple Named Pipes server for Windows, calling the Windows API (in Java with JNA but this is not relevant).

I am trying to figure out how to avoid that the server stays stuck forever waiting for a client to connect or for data to come from the client.

The server code does the following:

1) It creates the pipe by calling [`CreateNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), with `PIPE_WAIT` in the `dwPipeMode` argument.

2) It calls [`ConnectNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which doesn't return until a client has connected.

3) It enters a loop where it repeatedly reads a message from the client by calling [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which doesn't return until data is read, and for each received message it sends a message back to the client in response by calling `WriteFile`.

4) After many such conversations the client and the server will disconnect from the pipe.

I just would like to be able to set timeouts in the wait for `ConnectNamedPipe` at step 2 and `ReadFile` at step 3, and I can't see where to set the timeouts. There is the `nDefaultTimeOut` argument in `CreateNamedPipe` function, but it doesn't really sound to be intended for that; the API doc says:

*The default time-out value, in milliseconds, if the `WaitNamedPipe` function specifies `NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT`*.

So the `nDefaultTimeOut` arg in `CreateNamedPipe` sounds like the default timeout that *the clients* which would connect to the pipe would use for their operations and only if they call the `WaitNamedPipe` function. In fact in my tests values of 0 or 1000 don't make a difference, the call to `ConnectNamedPipe` never returns (unless a client connects). What I'm looking for is timeouts in the server instead, on the calls to `ConnectNamedPipe` and `ReadFile`.

As the doc of [`CreateNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for the `dwPipeMode` argument with `PIPE_WAIT` says, `Blocking mode is enabled. When the pipe handle is specified in the ReadFile, WriteFile, or ConnectNamedPipe function, the operations are not completed until there is data to read, all data is written, or a client is connected. Use of this mode can mean waiting indefinitely in some situations for a client process to perform an action.`

So maybe the way to implement such timeouts is to create the pipe in non-blocking mode (with `PIPE_NOWAIT` instead of `PIPE_WAIT`) so that calls to `ReadFile`, `WriteFile` and `ConnectNamedPipe` return immediately, and then somehow monitor myself the event (client connected or data received) in a loop, and check myself within the loop whether a timeout elapsed or another interrupting event occurred (like the user clicking a Cancel button) ?

**ADDED**: It looks like for the `ReadFile` call I might be able to use `PeekNamedPipe` which returns immediately, to check if there is data to read, and only then call `ReadFile`. I will try that. But I still have the same problem for the call to `ConnectNamedPipe`.

**ADDED**: As I suspected and the answers confirmed, being a novice to pipes I was looking at them from a somehow skew angle, from which the need for timeouts appeared greater than it actually is.

F.ex. the reasoning behind wanting to timeout calls to `ReadFile` was that if I (the server) am inside it reading data from the client and the client suddenly shuts down, sometimes I might end up stuck inside the `ReadFile`. But now I know that if the `ReadFile` is reading from a pipe and the client shuts down, the `ReadFile` will *always* error out, so the execution won't be stuck inside it.

Comment: As Melis suggests, asynchronous I/O is the correct approach.  Note in particular that PIPE_NOWAIT only exists for backwards compatibility and shouldn't typically be used in new code.  More importantly, timing out ConnectNamedPipe is a little unusual: are you sure this is what you want to do?  It doesn't really make sense unless you know that there should always be at least one client trying to connect.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I never worked with Named Pipes before, so I'm not too sure. But I'm thinking that when there is no client trying to connect, the execution stays inside ConnectNamedPipe, and if the server in that moment decides to close the pipe and shutdown, it needs ConnectNamedPipe to return, in order to call at least CloseHandle. Also, if ConnectNamedPipe doesn't return I cannot check f.ex. if the user has pressed the Esc key or clicked the Cancel button. Maybe I'm not using ConnectNamedPipe in the right way ? BTW in my use case most of the time there is no client trying to connect.

Comment: OK, needing to listen for messages of one sort or another isn't really the same thing as needing to time out, which is why I was a bit confused.  But they are a perfect example of a situation where asynchronous I/O is useful!  (There is an alternative, you could have multiple threads, but asynchronous I/O is more efficient.)  You would probably want to use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() in this scenario, to avoid polling.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't follow, it's likely that my design (the 4 points in my Q) is not right. I do need to wait for a client to connect, but I also need that the user can interrupt this waiting, and I don't know how to do that if `ConnectNamedPipe` never returns until a client connects. I thought I'd have `ConnectNamedPipe` to time out every few seconds, check if the user had asked for termination, and if not just call `ConnectNamedPipe` again and repeat. But I think I was off-track, I will look into `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, thanks also for pointing out that `PIPE_NOWAIT` is deprecated.

Comment: I just found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078433/named-pipe-wait-for-client-in-background-until-client-connects) that is about the same problem as the ConnectNamedPipe part of my question.

Comment: *I don't know how to do that if ConnectNamedPipe never returns until a client connects* - if you make the pipe asynchronous, ConnectNamedPipe (and ReadFile, for that matter) will always return immediately.  The operation will continue in the background, and when it completes the event object will be set.  When you notice that this has happened, you call GetOverlappedResult to find out whether the operation was successful.

Comment: This isn't really an answer since it doesn't answer the question.  If you control the entire conversation of both ends of the pipe and KNOW there will be a connection within a certain period of time, you can kind of cheat with a standard Event object where you can call `WaitForSingleObject()`.  That's what I did for my named pipe server in my [command-line CreateProcess tool](https://github.com/cubiclesoft/createprocess-windows).  Basically, it sets up an event object, waits on that object.  If it is signaled before the timeout, THEN it waits for a client to connect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some real-world code to demonstrate the asynchronous use of the server end of a pipe, in a GUI application:

```
void wait_for_object(HANDLE object)
{
  DWORD dw;
  MSG msg;

  for (;;) 
  {
    dw = MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, &object, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT, 0);

    if (dw == WAIT_OBJECT_0) break;
    if (dw == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) 
    {
      while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) DispatchMessage(&msg);
      continue;
    }
    srvfail(L"sleep() messageloop", GetLastError());
  }
}

HANDLE server_pipe;
HANDLE io_event;

void pipe_connection(void)
{
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    DWORD dw, err;

    SecureZeroMemory(&overlapped, sizeof(overlapped));
    overlapped.hEvent = io_event;

    if (!ReadFile(server_pipe, input_buffer, sizeof(input_buffer) - 1, NULL, &overlapped))
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        if (err == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            wait_for_object(io_event);
            if (!GetOverlappedResult(server_pipe, &overlapped, &dw, FALSE)) 
            {
                srvfail(L"Read from pipe failed asynchronously.", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            srvfail(L"Read from pipe failed synchronously.", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!GetOverlappedResult(server_pipe, &overlapped, &dw, FALSE)) 
        {
            srvfail(L"GetOverlappedResult failed reading from pipe.", GetLastError());
        }
    }

    input_buffer[dw] = '\0';

    process_command();

    if (!WriteFile(server_pipe, &output_struct, 
        ((char *)&output_struct.output_string - (char *)&output_struct) + output_struct.string_length, 
        NULL, &overlapped))
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        if (err == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            wait_for_object(io_event);
            if (!GetOverlappedResult(server_pipe, &overlapped, &dw, FALSE)) 
            {
                srvfail(L"Write to pipe failed asynchronously.", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            srvfail(L"Write to pipe failed synchronously.", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!GetOverlappedResult(server_pipe, &overlapped, &dw, FALSE)) 
        {
            srvfail(L"GetOverlappedResult failed writing to pipe.", GetLastError());
        }
    }

    if (!FlushFileBuffers(server_pipe)) srvfail(L"FlushFileBuffers failed.", GetLastError());
    if (!DisconnectNamedPipe(server_pipe)) srvfail(L"DisconnectNamedPipe failed.", GetLastError());
}

void server(void)
{
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    DWORD err, dw; 

    // Create the named pipe

    server_pipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipe_name, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, 1, buffer_size, buffer_size, 0, NULL);
    if (server_pipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) srvfail(L"CreateNamedPipe failed.", GetLastError());

    // Wait for connections

    io_event = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (io_event == NULL) srvfail(L"CreateEvent(io_event) failed.", GetLastError());

    for (;;)
    {
        SecureZeroMemory(&overlapped, sizeof(overlapped));
        overlapped.hEvent = io_event;

        if (!ConnectNamedPipe(server_pipe, &overlapped))
        {
            err = GetLastError();
            if (err == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED)
            {
                pipe_connection();
            }
            else if (err == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                wait_for_object(io_event);
                if (!GetOverlappedResult(server_pipe, &overlapped, &dw, FALSE)) 
                {
                    srvfail(L"Pipe connection failed asynchronously.", GetLastError());
                }
                pipe_connection();
            }
            else
            {
                srvfail(L"Pipe connection failed synchronously.", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!GetOverlappedResult(server_pipe, &overlapped, &dw, FALSE)) 
            {
                srvfail(L"GetOverlappedResult failed connecting pipe.", GetLastError());
            }
            pipe_connection();
        }
    }
}
```

(This code has been edited down from the original to remove extraneous logic.  I haven't tried compiling the edited version, so there may be some minor problems.  Also note the use of global variables, which is OK in my case because the application is very small, but should *usually* be avoided.)

The use of MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx() allows window messages to be processed while you are waiting for I/O to complete.  If you were also waiting for something else to happen, you could pass it an array of handles rather than just a single handle - for example, if you wanted to monitor a child process and do something when it exited, you could pass an array containing both `io_event` and the process handle.  And if you just *had* to do some other job periodically, you could set a timeout for the wait, or use a window timer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example and for the info, I learned a lot from this and from @Melis answer. I added that at the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you set `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and use an event to check/wait for completion.

Although this is originally intended for asynchronous IO, you can instead time the event to your predefined time to live.

If you then wanted to cancel the I/O operation, you can use the CancelIo() function.  If you just wanted to do some work and then resume waiting, you can do that too - timing out the wait doesn't automatically cancel the I/O, so you would not need to call ConnectNamedPipe again.

You could also, as you yourself suggested set `PIPE_NOWAIT` and poll the connection until successfull, either way should bring the same result in this use case.  Note however that this is legacy functionality and Microsoft discourage use of this option.